# Bad URI - CkEditor and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I came back to an old project and wanted to fire up the server and see how it looks. I started getting those errors:

```
bad URI(is not URI?): file-digest:///.../app/assets/config/ckeditor
```

I was about to change every image link from assets to a link from CDN anyway, so I did. But then came the same error with this line highlighted:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', debug: false %>
```

What might be going on?

I have a `gem CKEditor` installed so I can post blog posts on my website, but there was no problem a month or so ago when I uploaded the site to a heroku server, and everything is running fine there. What might be causing the bad URI error?

Any code connected with CKEditor below:

**app/config/Application.rb**

```
module App
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater
    config.i18n.available_locales = [:pl, :en]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :pl

    config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
    config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* )
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
  end
end
```

**app/config/initializers/ckeditor.rb**

```
# Use this hook to configure ckeditor
Ckeditor.setup do |config|

  require "ckeditor/orm/active_record"

end
```

Comment: Please please say you solved this? I've got the same problem.

Comment: @BenSmith I ended up removing the gem completely and using their cdn. Much easier as I did not have time to solve it the "right way".

Comment: thanks for getting back to me, what do you mean by their "cdn"?